# Is it possible to connect PSP Street to TV?

Tags: psp, streaming, homebrew

Some time ago I bought again PlayStation Portable E1004 Street. I decided to buy this version because of the price of second-hand markets and I have no special requirements about it.

But I started to consider streaming gameplay to my TV to be able to play in more comfortable circumstances - sitting on the couch and watching the game on a quite bigger screen than this embedded in this little console.

I know that some versions of PSP have special output allowing connection with TV (I know, that games designed for PSP resolution could look so ugly on the big TV, but let's skip this case), but PSP Street has deprived this functionality.

Despite this, is it any way to set the connection between PSP Street and TV without this TV Out socket on the console? Does exist any homebrew software allowing some connection by micro USB socket, which is present in PSP Street? Or maybe there is another way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method I'm aware of is by using Remote Joy Lite via custom firmware.

Here is the description found from [this page](https://www.reddit.com/r/PSP/wiki/remotejoy).:

"Remote Joy Lite is a plugin for the PSP that allows the user to stream the PSP screen to their computer. This works for Windows only and is a great tool if you are looking to record gameplay or play slower paced games on a larger screen. The output is still the resolution of the PSP similar to using an output cable to a TV. Some games are known to not work with the plugin. It can be used on the XMB, PSP/PSX games, and emulators or homebrew."